# Yii2: How to use Date Control class of Krajee widget

Tags: yii2

I am developing form with birthdate in it as a field. I am trying to show calander when user clicks on text field.

I followed steps given for datePicker see [this](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol)

I did all the installation & configuration. when i run the page it shows me error that

```
Fatal error: Class 'Module' not found in C:....taging\frontend\config\main.php on line 89
```

how is module class defined in main.php or else where to define???

Comment: Show your current config.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you posted. Do you have this

```
use kartik\datecontrol\Module;
```

at the top of the config file? It is required. It is used in the configuration.

Comment: should it be in the main.php. i tried writing it there but still it shows the error...!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you add these two lines at the top of your form:

```
use kartik\datecontrol\Module;
use kartik\datecontrol\DateControl;
```